# Undefined behavior, or: Does Swift have sequence points?

Tags: swift, undefined-behavior, sequence-points

In C/C++, the second statement in

```
int i = 0;
int j = i++ + i++ + ++i;
```

invokes both

- *unspecified behavior*, because the order of evaluation of operands
  is unspecified, and
- *undefined behavior*, because the side effects on the same object `i` are unsequenced relative to each other.

See for example

- [Why are these constructs (using ++) undefined behavior?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/949433/why-are-these-constructs-using-undefined-behavior)
- [Undefined behavior and sequence points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176328/undefined-behavior-and-sequence-points)

Now, given that Swift was designed as a *safe* language, what is the
corresponding situation here? Is the result of

```
var i = 0
let j = i++ + i++ + ++i
```

well-defined? Can one conclude from the language reference in the
Swift book that `j == 4`?

Comment: This is a good question to ask, but unfortunately, I have a feeling that the answer is currently "nobody knows"...

Comment: @jtbandes: Thanks (but somebody disagrees :) – You are probably right. I have now cross-posted this in the Apple Developer Forum, perhaps that gives some feedback: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/20001.

Comment: Awesome — Chris Lattner responded. I was secretly hoping the answer was "left to right" :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The question was answered by Apple developer and Swift designer Chris
Lattner in the Apple Developer Forum https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/20001#63783:

> Yes, the result of that expression will always be 4.  Swift evaluates
>   expressions left to right, it isn't undefined or implementation
>   defined behavior like C.

Chris also added:

> That said, if you write code like that, someone trying to maintain it
>   will probably not be very happy with you

Agreed! It was meant as an extreme example to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: An update: per the now open-source [Swift Evolution]9https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0004-remove-pre-post-inc-decrement.md) process, `--` and `++` are to be removed from future Swift versions.

Comment: @rickster: You are right, thanks for adding the info here! – But even without these operators, the fact that Swift evaluates expressions left to right remains interesting (in my opinion).