# Order of evaluation with a tuple

Tags: swift, tuples, operator-precedence

With this:

```
let (resultA, resultB, resultC) = (a(), b(), c())
```

What is the order of execution?

1. `a()`, then `b()`, then `c()`, then set `resultA`, then set `resultB`, then set `resultC`
2. undefined

Any reference or documentation on the expected behavior?

Comment: execution order will be as you described in the first option.
that is 1(), then b(), then c()

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32705320/undefined-behavior-or-does-swift-have-sequence-points. I assume that Chris Lattner's statement *"Swift evaluates expressions left to right"* applies here as well.

Comment: Thanks @MartinR, would you like to answer so that I mark it as accepted, or would you like to close it as duplicate?